# Comparing two file csv, and create a new file with element in common, but the compiler report me ValueError

Tags: python, pandas

I recently started using python for a project, so I apologize in advance for my inexperience.
I’m working with two different csv files, but they’re all in a common field. csv files contain information about a series of books and are of different sizes. File one has the field 'description', file two does not. The field that unites files is 'isbn'. My goal is to create a . csv file that contains the description of the books with the same isbn code. My code is:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

dataset_description = '../dataset-books/dataset.csv'
books_mod = '../dataset-books/booksmod.csv'
output_file = '../dataset-books/newdataset.csv'
cols_to_remove = [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]

cols_to_remove = sorted(cols_to_remove, reverse=True)
row_count = 0 # Current amount of rows processed

with open(dataset_description, "r", encoding='Latin1') as source,\
open(books_mod, 'r', encoding='Latin1') as source2:
reader = pd.read_csv(source, delimiter=',')
reader2 = pd.read_csv(source2, delimiter=',')
with open(output_file, "w", newline='', encoding='Latin1') as result:
    writer = csv.writer(result)
    for row, row2 in reader, reader2:
#row[19], row2[6] index column containing the code
        if row[19] == row2[6] and row_count != 10001:
            for col_index in cols_to_remove:
                del row[col_index]
            writer.writerow([row_count, row])
            row_count += 1
        else:
            break
source.close()
source2.close()
result.close()
```

I read the csv files, I define the indexes of the columns I want to delete, I open the files for reading and one for writing and I try to select only the rows that have the same code and delete the others. Finally I write everything on a file. At the time of execution it brings me the error:'ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)'.
Please, help me!

Comment: [pandas.merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html?highlight=merge) is a great function you can use for this.

Comment: I tried, but it gives me back: UserWarning: You are merging on int and float columns where the float values are not equal to their int representation
  UserWarning,
Empty DataFrame
Columns: return a join of attributes.
Index: []

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution with pandas.merge().

ensure that datatype of the "on" merge field is the same. In this case, ISBN has been read as float64.

```
import numpy as np df3=pd.read_csv("text.csv",dtype={'isbn': np.float64})
```

```
import pandas as pd
f1=pd.DataFrame({"isbn":[1,2,3,5],"Authors":['A','B','C','D']})
f2=pd.DataFrame({"isbn":[2,3,5],"Description":["Book two","Book Three","Book 4"]})
df=pd.merge(f1,f2,on=['isbn'],indicator=True)
```

Comment: I tried, but it gives me back: UserWarning: You are merging on int and float columns where the float values are not equal to their int representation UserWarning, Empty DataFrame Columns: return a join of attributes. Index: [] Code:merge_data = pd.merge(reader, reader2, on='isbn13', indicator=True)

Comment: the warning seems to be coming from datatype of isbn. can you check the data type of isbn13 in reader and reader2, you can try by `reader.dtypes` and `reader2.dtypes`

Comment: in the reader is int64, reader2 is a float64. How i can converted reader2 from float64 to int64?

Comment: one way is , when you read the csv, define its datatype `import numpy as np
df3=pd.read_csv("text.csv",dtype={'isbn': np.float64})` in this example isbn will be float64.

Comment: Thank you very much!